# Why is this LFSR not always shifting correctly?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, shift

I have this 32-bit LFSR function:

```
def wu32(i):
    # wrap unsigned 32 bit integer
    return long(i % pow(2,32))

def iterate_lfsr(state):
    return wu32(wu32(0x00000000L - wu32(state & 0x00000001L)) & 0xd0000001L) ^ wu32(state>>1)
```

For testing I put together this function, which performs a certain number of LFSR iterations (and thus bit shifts) on an input number, and then prints the number in hex format.

```
def i_lfsr(state,times):
    cstate = state
    for i in range(times):
        cstate = iterate_lfsr(cstate)
    print str(hex(-1 & cstate))
```

---

I'm testing this LFSR with the number 0x12345678 and shifting it by one byte each time:

```
>>> i_lfsr(0x12345678L,0)
0x12345678L
>>> i_lfsr(0x12345678L,8)
0x39123456L
>>> i_lfsr(0x12345678L,16)
0x2d791234L
>>> i_lfsr(0x12345678L,24)
0x87ad7913L
>>> i_lfsr(0x12345678L,32)
0x9727ad78L
```

It almost works correctly, but the bytes are being modified slightly. Note how 0x39 becomes 0x79, 0x2d becomes 0xad, 0x12 becomes 0x13, 0x87 becomes 0x27, and 0x79 becomes 0x78. This shouldn't happen - the bitwise shifts should have eventually moved everything over one byte at a time while filling in new bytes from the other side.

I expected to see output closer to the following sequence (an example, of course):

```
0x12345678
0xef123456
0xbeef1234
0xadbeef12
0xdeadbeef
```

Why are the bytes being mangled, and what should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
return long(i % pow(2,32))
```

Do not use floating point when exact results are required. Use AND, OR, and shifts.

Comment: The modulo operator casts its operands to floating point? I've been looking through the docs but I can't figure out how to get the integer overflow effect with bitwise operators.

Comment: No, `pow` is the problem. Take a `1` and shift it left instead of raising `2` to a power! Use something more like `i % (1 << 32)` or `i & (1 << 32)`.

Comment: `return long(i % (1<<32))` doesn't seem to make any difference for me.

Comment: You mean you get the exact same results?

Comment: Yep, I get the exact same results. Tested using a new clean shell.